# get file path of selected files in kendo UI upload

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-upload

how to get the file path of selected files in kendo UI upload element. we can get the name and size of files but is there any way to get the full path of file?

Comment: why do you require file path ,as you know it is fileupload which takes file as input and upload to server. can you explain your requirement ?As kendo upload exposed on file name and file size .

Comment: I want to use kendo upload inside my kendo ui mobile application I could select files in android and ios but I need the path of the selected files to upload that file using cordova file transfer